# Using OpenLayers' Refresh strategy for GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, openlayers-2

I am trying to use the Refresh Strategy reading a GeoJSON file in OpenLayers, however it doesn't work (but it works perfectly using for instance .Fixed() strategy), here is my code:

```
    var acediot_map = {};
    var map;

    function initMap() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("info");
        var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        map.addLayer(mapnik);

        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

        var myStyles = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                pointRadius: 10,
                fillColor: "${getColor}",
                strokeWidth: 1,
                strokeColor: "#800026",
                fillOpacity: 1.0
            },
            {
                context: {
                    getColor : function (feature) {
                        return feature.attributes.severity == 'LOW' ? '#FFFF00' :
                            feature.attributes.severity == 'MID'    ? '#FF8C00' :
                            feature.attributes.severity == 'HIGH'   ? '#FF0000' :
                                                                      '#7CFC00' ;
                    }
                }
            })
        });


        var myInterval = 5000;

        acediot_map.report_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                strategies: [
                    new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({interval: myInterval})],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "myGeoReport.json",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
                }),
                styleMap: myStyles
        });


        acediot_map.location_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("LocationLayer", {
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "myGeoLocation.json",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })
        });

        overlays = [acediot_map.report_layer, acediot_map.location_layer];
        map.addLayers(overlays);

        map.setCenter(
            new OpenLayers.LonLat(9.2257418, 45.4788448).transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                map.getProjectionObject()
            ), 13
        );
}
```

And here is an example of my GeoJSON file

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features":[
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          9.2257418,
          45.4788448
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "accuracy": 20.0,
        "description": "Prima prova ",
        "notes": "",
        "picture": "",
        "severity": "LOW",
        "team": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Eugenio Gianniti",
          "org": "Politecnico di Milano"
        }, 
        "timestamp": 1411920949.921636
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try specifying a fixed strategy too.